# How to change a color of string/text in UI application build in java swing?

Tags: java, string, swing

I have a string/text that I want to show on UI made with java swing. I need to color that text. I was using HTML to color my string and it was working fine till now. But now we have to stop using HTML for coloring string for some reason. I am looking for other alternatives.

My existing approach was something like this:

```java
public class dummy{
    public static void main(String []args){
         System.out.println("<html><font color=red>"+"This is my simple text" +"</font></html>");    
    }
}
```

I have checked for JTREE Render, but that's for tree node coloring and that's not suiting my scenario. Any other suggestion is most welcomed.

Comment: [How to Use Labels](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html)

Answer (score 1):

This may help:

```
JButton b = new JButton("<html><center><b><u>D</u>isable</b><br>"
        + "<font color=#ffffdd>middle button</font>",
        leftButtonIcon);
b.setForeground(Color.RED);
b.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
```

Set color using `setForeground` and `setBackground` methods

[How to Use HTML in Swing Components](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html)